# From DropDownList to Textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have `DropDownList` and `Textbox` on my page.
`DropDownList` show data from `DataBase(Table "List").`
When I choose one line in `DropDownList` I want to see it in `Textbox`, make changes and save this line into `DataBase(Table "Text")` after press *"OK"*.

Please tell me, how to do this?

Code:

**Controller.cs:**

```
    public ActionResult Create(Model model)
    {         
        var viewModel = new ISMSViewModel
        {
            Model = new Model(),
        };

        return View(viewModel);

    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Model model, int i)
    {
        try
        {
            sysDB.AddToActives(model);
            sysDB.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Browse");

        }
    }
```

**ListText.ascx:**

```
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, new { Lists = Model.Lists } %>

            <%: Html.Label("List") %>
            <%: Html.DropDownList("ListId", new SelectList(ViewData["Lists"] as IEnumerable, "ListId", "Name", Model.ListId)) %>

            <%: Html.Label("TextBox") %>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TextBox) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextBox) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to write some JavaScript.

handle the onchange event for dropdown

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("ListId", new SelectList(ViewData["Lists"] as IEnumerable, "ListId", "Name", Model.ListId), new {@onchange="setVal(this)"}) %>
```

on your view
inside `head` block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setVal(obj)
{
document.getElementById("TextBox").value=obj.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but I could not realize this solution at my project. Would you be so kind and give me a link on some simple project with this solution in progress. Please do not judge strictly, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @sphinx can you give me your solution and I'll make change in that, is it ok?